# How to restrict wild card search on Oracle Unified Directory server for read only user

Tags: ldap

We have Oracle Unified Directory(OUD) with around 10 million users. We have read-only account that is used to for search operations on base dn. But sometimes this user account is being used to perform wildcard search like `(uid=*)` on base dn. This is causing timeout issues on OUD and impacting performance also. Is there a way to restrict this wildcard search on base dn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set resource limited on the user that is performing the wildcard search.
This will of course cause all the queries they run to be limited to the amount of entries set and have unknown consequences in whatever app is using the returned data.   It’s probably preferable to educate them on how to perform paged searches so you can still define limits and they can still consume the data.

Create an ldif file and run ldapmodify with limits suited for your environment.

```
dn: uid=baduser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: ds-rlim-lookthrough-limit
ds-rlim-lookthrough-limit: 10000
-
add: ds-rlim-size-limit
ds-rlim-size-limit: 5000
-
add: ds-rlim-time-limit
ds-rlim-time-limit: 300
```

Comment: Thanks. This suggestion will work. Will try this out.